# How to improve performance of background task in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, com, task-parallel-library

I'm building a WPF app which will do some heavy work in the background. The issue is that when I run the task in the unit tests, it usually takes about 6~7s to run. But when I run it using TPL in WPF app, it takes somewhere between 12s~30s to run. Is there a way to speed up this thing. I'm calling COM api of LogParser to do the real work.

**Update**:
My code for calling Log Parser API looks like below

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var logQuery = new LogQueryClassClass();
                var inputFormat = new COMEventLogInputContextClassClass
                {
                    direction = "FW",
                    fullText = true,
                    resolveSIDs = false,
                    formatMessage = true,
                    formatMsg = true,
                    msgErrorMode = "MSG",
                    fullEventCode = false,
                    stringsSep = "|",
                    iCheckpoint = string.Empty,
                    binaryFormat = "HEX"
                };
                try
                {
                    Debug.AutoFlush = true;
                    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    var recordset = logQuery.Execute(query, inputFormat);
                    watch.Stop();

                    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    while (!recordset.atEnd())
                    {
                        var record = recordset.getRecord();
                        recordProcessor(record);
                        recordset.moveNext();
                    }
                    recordset.close();
                    watch.Stop();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (logQuery != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(logQuery);
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(logQuery);
                        logQuery = null;
                    }
                }
            });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
```

The thing now is with this change, I can see about 3 - 4s improvement in debugging mode, but not when I hit **Ctrl + F5** to run it which is quite beyond me. How come??

Comment: If it is for a unit test, can you not mock the COM API or the objects being used within?

Comment: It's not for unit test, the issue is that in unit test, the performance is good, but not in the actual app.

Comment: How is cpu usage? For how many cores?

Comment: Do you create the COM object in the tasks or in the main (GUI) thread? The main GUI thread is STA so if the COM object is created there all COM calls from your tasks need to be marshalled back to the main thread. Your test is probably running MTA so no marshalling is needed

Comment: @adrianm, No, I'm actually creating the COM objects in the thread that runs that task. So this should not be the case.

Comment: @SimonMourier, the CPU usage is quite high during the querying and showing results period, after that, the usage is cooled down. Any idea?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I also tested the query performance of other methods like using the EventLogQuery class, the CPU usage is not as high (about 50% vs 90%).

Comment: Would you have a piece of code describing how exactly you use TPL, that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What does your recordProcessor do? I've tried your exact code, and can find no difference in performance inside or outside the debugger, and no difference whether using your `Thread` start code, or just running that thread body code directly on the main thread. So I'm trying to work out what might be different on my system. My `recordProcessor` does nothing, so I'm wondering if the problem could actually be in there?

Comment: @IanGriffiths, `recordProcessor` will marshal back to UI thread to update the UI

Comment: Well that is almost certainly a large part of the problem - if you're marshalling back to the UI thread every time you process a record, you are going to see horrible performance problems. See the link I added in the 2nd edit to my reply for an explanation of the details, and what you can do about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the COM object you're using will only run on an STA thread. Several people already suggested this, but I decided to check, just to be sure. I installed the LogParser SDK, and here's what it puts in the registry for the CLSID associated with the `MSUtil.LogQuery` ProgID:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66}]
@="LogQuery"
"AppID"="{3040E2D1-C692-4081-91BB-75F08FEE0EF6}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Log Parser 2.2\\LogParser.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66}\ProgID]
@="MSUtil.LogQuery.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="MSUtil.LogQuery"
```

It's that `"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"` that's the clincher. This COM class is declaring that it can only run on an STA thread.

Both the TPL and the `BackgroundWorker` use MTA threads. The consequence of this is that when you use the LogParser from either a TPL task or a `BackgroundWorker` the COM runtime detects that you're on the wrong kind of thread, and will either find or create an STA to host the object. (In this particular case it'll use what's called the 'host STA', a thread that COM creates specially for this purpose. There are some scenarios in which it'll use your main UI thread instead, but that's not the case here.)

COM then automatically marshals any calls from your worker thread over to that STA thread. It does this via a Windows message queue, so for each method you execute (and remember, property accessors are just methods in disguise, so this applies to property use too), your worker thread will send a message to that STA thread, that STA thread's message pump then has to pick that message up and dispatch it, at which point the COM runtime will call the method on the LogParser for you.

This is slow if you've got an API that involves a high volume of calls.

This is neither a WPF nor a Windows Forms issue by the way. It is entirely to do with using an STA-based COM object from a non-STA thread. You could reproduce exactly the same problem with a console app too, if you were using a non-STA thread in that. And the problem isn't specific to either the TPL or the `BackgroundWorker` - it will afflict anything that uses the thread pool, because thread pool threads all use MTA, not STA.

The solution is to use an STA thread. And the best way to do that is create a dedicated thread. Use the `Thread` class in the `System.Threading` namespace to launch your own thread. Call its `SetApartmentState` method before starting it. Make sure that the code that creates instances of objects from the LogParser API is running on that thread, and also make sure that you only ever use those objects from that thread. This should fix your performance issues.

**Edited 21st Feb 2013 to clarify:**

Note that it's not simply enough to ensure that you are using the COM object from an STA thread. You must use if from *the same STA thread on which you created it*. Basically, the whole reason for having the STA model is to enable COM components to use a single-threaded model. It enables them to assume that everything that happens to them happens on one thread. If you write multi-threaded .NET code that uses an STA thread from multiple threads, it will, under the covers, ensure that the COM object gets what it wants, meaning that all access will go through the thread it belongs to.

This means that if you call it from some other thread than its home STA thread, then even if that other thread also happens to be an STA thread, you'll still be paying the cross-thread price.

**Edited 25th Feb 2013 to add:**

(Not sure if this is relevant to this particular question, but could well be of interest to other people landing on this question through a search.) A downside of moving work onto a separate worker thread is that if you want to update the UI in any way as a result of processing these records, you're now on the wrong thread. If you're using databinding an `INotifyPropertyChanged`, WPF will automatically handle the cross-thread change notification for you, but this can have significant performance implications. If you need to do a lot of work on a background thread, but that work needs to end up updating the UI, you may need to take steps to batch those updates. It's not completely trivial - see the series of blog entries starting here: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2013/02/14/wpf-async-too-fast

Comment: or use the StaTaskScheduler from TPL Extras. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx

Comment: I used both methods, use StaTaskScheduler to make sure that my background thread is STA, and also start a new STA thread to call the LogParser COM API, but it has only noticeable improvement when I am debugging the code. When I run it, there is no improvement whatsoever, odd.

Comment: Are you doing anything to ensure that you're always using the *same* STA thread? If you have multiple STA threads in your app (which will be the case if you specify a concurrency level of more than 1 with the `StaTaskScheduler`, and it will also be the case if you use both the TPL and the `new Thread` approach, or if you create multiple threads explicitly) it'll only go fast if you happen to use the COM object on the same STA thread from which you created it.

Comment: @IanGriffiths, I did specify 2 as the concurrency level for `StaTaskScheduler` and I also used the `new Thread` for creating a STA thread to do the COM calling. So I guess what I should do is specify 1 as the concurrency level and do not use the `new Thread` for calling COM. I'll try this out. But your analysis still hasn't answer the reason why in debug mode we had a 3 seconds gain. This issue indeed puzzles me a great deal.

Comment: The debug mode difference could be due to the non-deterministic nature of multithreaded code - running in a debugger often causes things to happen at a different speed. It's possible that a subtle change in timing led to a change in how the `StaTaskScheduler` decided to allocate work to threads, meaning that you happened to get lucky and end up on the right thread in the debugger. (Alternatively, the debugger's property viewer can occasionally cause things to happen on different threads from normal, but I don't see an obvious way that would cause the problem you're seeing.)

Comment: Actually...looking at your update of your original question, it looks like you've removed the TPL from the picture completely, and you're just using a single dedicated Thread? So my debugger suggestion wouldn't hold. I've just tried your code on a simple test query: `SELECT TOP 5000 SourceName, EventID, Message FROM System` and it takes 1.14 seconds whether I run it on the main thread, or use your threading code, and it behaves the same in and out of the debugger. In short, I can't repro what you're describing, and I'm using your code. There must be a missing detail.

Comment: I think I'll give up on this, seems impossible. I removed the `new Thread...` and `recordProcessor` and use StaTaskScheduler, but the code behave exactly the same - debug mode usually has 3~5s gain over just running the program and the latter consistent shows no perf gain at all. Looks like WPF and COM don't work well together

Comment: I think a dedicated thread would actually be a better approach than the `StaTaskScheduler` here. You need to have precisely one thread on which all the LogParser work happens. The TPL abstracts away threading details, which is usually good, but that's the opposite of what you want here. As for your debug vs. non-debug behaviour, I couldn't repro that with a simple example, but as mentioned elsewhere, if you're sending off work to the dispatcher thread every time round the loop, that's probably a big part of your perf problem.

Answer (score 2):

COM uses message queues for IPC. I'm unclear what determines *which* message queue, but I suspect it's the shell message queue because the Delphi debugger and Outlook used to play merry hell with each other. My unproven hypothesis is that an out of process COM server can be stalled by something *else* stallings the shell message queue. Windows has timeouts to prevent this sort of thing from totally locking up the system but it can cause massive slowdown in affected processes. My solution would be to avoid COM. You could check this by commenting out the parts that actually use COM and timing the process.

Comment: The problem is that in a winform app, the perf is inline with the unit test one. And I have to use COM since LogParser has no other API available that I know of.

Comment: In your Windows Forms app, are you also using TPL? I'm trying to work out whether this problem is specific to the fact that you're using WPF, or whether it's actually something to do with using TPL vs whatever it is you're doing in your Windows Forms app. (From what you've said, the most likely culprit is COM apartment model mismatches, but I don't yet have enough information to be certain.)

Comment: @IanGriffiths, I tried using BackgroundWorker, which is what the demo Winform app used, and the performance hasn't changed at all.